# Message not sending to Server from Client - Java

Tags: java, client, server, lan

I have a `Server-Client` program where I send a small messsage to the client using `JLabel`. When that message is recieved from server that particular client must send a response immediately. But it is not sending any message . Can somebody look at my code and tell me where my mistake is?

//SERVER

```
void connect_clients()
    {
        try {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7700);
            jButton1.setText("Server Running!");
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
                while (true) {

                    socket = listener.accept();
                    socketList.add(socket);
                    //socketList.add(listener.accept());
                     BufferedReader ed = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String tmp = ed.readLine();
             System.out.print("I Recieved :"+tmp);

                }

            }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
        }
    }
```

//CLIENT

```
 void connect_server() throws IOException
    {
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
            String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
                            "running the date service on port 9090:");
            s = new Socket(serverAddress, 7700);

            while(true){
            BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String answer = input.readLine();
            System.out.println(answer);
                if(answer != null)
                {
                    PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    InputStreamReader rd = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                    BufferedReader ed = new BufferedReader(rd);
                    String temp = ed.readLine();
                    pr.println(temp);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Answer is not null");  //THIS WORKS
               }

            }

          }
       catch (ConnectException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
         catch (SocketException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How exactly the server is sending the first message after accepting the connection?

Comment: Message is sent to clients thought a click on JLabel which i haven't showed here @me_digvijay

Answer (score 1):

Some points that you missed in your implementation:

- the streams and sockets are never closed
- in the client i do not see the point of the endless loop
- the client should initialize the communication by sending a message via output stream (not to try to read first)

For a simple example the steps should be:

1. Start sever to listen and once a connection is established to read the message (you did)
2. The client should sent a message via output stream and close the steams and the socket
3. The severs should close the streams and the sockect for the established connection

Example:

```
//Server
socket = listener.accept();
BufferedReader ed = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter pr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
String tmp = ed.readLine();
System.out.print("I Recieved :"+tmp);
String msg = "Message received";
pr.write(msg,0,msg.length());
pr.newLine();
ed.close();
pr.close();
socket.close();

//Client
BufferedWriter pr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String sendMessage = "Send Message";
pr.write(msg,0,msg.length());
pr.newLine();
String answer = input.readLine();
System.out.println(answer);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Answer is not null"); 
input.close();
pr.close();
s.close();
```

**UPDATE**

reading from input stream continuously:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String line;
while((line=input.readLine())!=null){ 
  //do something with line
}
```

Comment: 1.Stream and sockets aren't close because if i close the program execution is done and then i can't send anymore messages. 2.to receive the message from server continuesly i have the 'while' loop or else the program terminates as soon as it receives the first message. 3.I have read the message from the server. The whole idea is to send a small message to clients from the server so that it will send a file it's like request a file from the client by sending a message. @Stephan

Comment: 1. i get the picture but at same point you will need to close them 2. you do not need an endless loop to receive messages you just need a loop that read from the stream till the end (the declaration of the input reader should be outside of the loop)

Comment: 1.will i be able to send message if they are closed?  2. I don't get this?  How do you implement a loop only for reading from the streams?

Comment: 1. i meant you should keep them opened as long as you need but after you do not need them then you should close them. 2. you need something like : declare input reader , while reader has data then read and after data ended close the socket

Comment: Yes I'm clear now. But what is my problem(except from the point you suggested) I'm my code? Why am i not able to send message to server?

Comment: Because you first try to read a message from the server which you will never receive since the server expects a message as well... first you need in the client to write a message via output steam to the server

Comment: By my applications needs the server to request from client to send the system details of the clients. I don't see any other way from where the server can request except sending a message as a request.

Comment: So you what the server to notify the client? not the other way around ?

Comment: Yes i want the server to send a message so that the client can understand there is a request form the server then the client will send the files to server.

Comment: Ok then the client should have `ServerSocket` to listen for connections from the server

Comment: Why will the client listen for connection? As it is already been connected to thr server?

Comment: because you said that the server should notify the clients not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a simple approach where server is sending the hi msg to client.

For server:

```
//Server
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(3554);
socket = ss.accept();
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getOutputStream()));
String msg ="Hi from server"
bw.write(msg);
String msgFromClient=br.readLine();
System.out.println(msgFromClient);
bw.close();
socket.close();
```

For Client:

```
//Client
Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",3554)
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())); 
String received = input.readLine();
System.out.println(received);
bw.write("Client recieve :"+received);
br.close();
bw.close();
socket.close();
```

Comment: I'm able to send messages from server to clients. My problem is I'm not able to send back message from client to server.

Comment: for continuous send and recieve you can have loop for that.

Comment: You can loop the server and client code or you can make it thread base application